# Error parsing JSON: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My code:

```
    a = AppParam.find_by key: 'lowest_price'

    json.set! :response do
        json.array!(@products) do |product|
        json.extract! product, :id, :name, :description, :icon, :price, :tax, :is_active
        json.url product_url(product, format: :json)
    end

    json.extract! a, :value
```

Throws this error:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer in json.extratct! a, :value
```

Comment: can you post your json response.